# Android-HeapWorker Error

Tags: android

I am getting this error after use my app for some period of time.

```
HeapWorker is wedged: 23883ms spent inside Landroid/database/sqlite/SQLiteCursor;.finalize()V
```

I saw two similar questions, and they say to close some Cursors open, but I am not using SQLite. I just save few variables in SharedPreferences.

Someone could explain me what this error means?

I am using this modified class of SharedPreferences to save an Array of Strings.

https://github.com/kcochibili/TinyDB--Android-Shared-Preferences-Turbo

It already commit every time I save something.
My MainActivity, where the app crashes, doesn't even use this connection.

I am doing something like this.
OBS: the default for getBolean is False.

```
TinyDB tinydb = new TinyDB(context);
if(!tinydb.getBolean("isFirstTime")){
   List <String> array = new ArrayList<String>();
   //set the array
   tinydb.putBolean("isFirstTime",true);
   tinydb.putList("array",array);
   //startMainActivity
}else{
   //startMainActivity
}
```

Comment: have you forgotten to call commit or apply?

Comment: I edit the question, all the methods put of this class already commit at the end of the method.

Comment: Are you certain this error is 100% relevant to your code and app?

Comment: It crashes after I got this error. I remove all instances of TinyDB of my code just to test, and now I got a strange message: 
"sqlite3_close(0x25e920) failed: 5" But I am not even working with sqlite anymore.